# Sort java.util.Deque

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

I want to sort the contents of my `Deque<Card>` collection using the `Card` class' `getRealValue()` method.

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  private final int value;
  private final CardType cardType;

  public Card(int value, CardType cardType) {
    this.value = value;
    this.cardType = cardType;
  }

  public int getRealValue() {
    int realValue = this.value == 1 ? 52 : 0;
    return realValue + this.value * 4 + this.cardType.ordinal();
  }

  public int compareTo(Card o) {
    return this.getRealValue() - o.getRealValue();
  }
}
```

Here is my CardType enum

```
public enum CardType {
    CLUB("♣"),
    SPADE("♠"), 
    HEART("♥"), 
    DIAMOND("♦"); 

    public final String icon;

    private CardType(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

and I want to sort my Deque based on the `realValue()`

Comment: implement the `compareTo` method in `Card`… Otherwise, `implements Comparable<Card>` is somehow useless.

Comment: You can't sort a deque, it's a queue. So, copy it into a list, sort it using a comparator, and then put back into a seque.

Comment: I implemented the `compareTo()`, it just happened, I did't put all the codes, Updating the question now to put the `compareTo()`.

Comment: What implementation of `Deque` are you using? Could you show the code where it is used?

Comment: I am using `ArrayDeque<Card>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can always clear it and re-insert the elements in the right order:

```
Card[] a = deque.toArray(new Card[0]);
Arrays.sort(a);
deque.clear();
for (Card card : a) {
    deque.add(card);
}
```

Bear in mind the performance of this. If sorting is a requirement of your structure, consider using a `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop, you can use [`Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) (which, at least in OpenJDK, is implemented the same way: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l5429, https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/cd766db99c40/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l5562).